# Open python interpreter on intellij

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea

I'm new with python 3.3.

I'm using intellij IDEA 12.1.6.

How can I open the interpreter window, the one with the '>>>' prompt?

Thanks

Comment: I don't use that IDE so can't help. But if you're desperate to get something done open terminal/commandline and type `python` and you've got yourself a Python interpreter :P

Comment: So just open commandline and type `python`. Or use IDLE (it normally comes as default with almost any Python distribution).

Comment: If you own the Ultimate edition, you can install the Python plugin (http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/631) and simply run (`^R`) a python script in the built-in console.

Answer (score 19):

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 Ultimate with the [JetBrains Python Plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/)  3.4.135.24.

After installing the plugin and restarting the IDE, I can open the iPython console [exactly the same way as in PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/running-console.html), i.e. clicking `Tools` -> `Run Python Console` in the menu.

Another option is by selecting some code in a `.py` file, right clicking and choosing `Execute Line/Selection in Console` or pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. If the console has not been opened already, it will open now.

Using the console integrated in the IDE has a few advantages over running iPython alongside it, as listed at in the linked PyCharm documentation page.

Comment: `alt-shift-e` is an intellij MVP gem

Comment: I'd like to point out that none of these options in the menus exist until you go into your project and define a default python interpreter.  I was going crazy calling everyone liars when these menu options didn't exist, but once I went to File -> Project Structure, Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK, and added a new one for python, it worked!  I pointed at /usr/bin/python.  Then thins like Tools -> Run Python Console showed up.

Answer (score 6):

**Go To Tools -> Python Console**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to program python exclusively you may have a look at Intellij's little brother PyCharm. It is specifically designed for python development: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Under PyCharm you can open an interactive Python session by selecting Menu->Tools->Run Python Console...

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij (community edition) in terminal (I use Linux, this might differ in your case) I type `python3` and it works the same way as in pycharm. With "_" as return value etc. I find this rather useful.